# Get Data from the APNS Message

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification

Hi I am looking for a way to read the Remote PushNotification without the function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

The contra of this function is, I have to click on the Notification, then will call this function, but how can I read the Message if I am clicking the App icon from the Homescreen?

Have someone an Idea?

Many Thanks

Greetings
Simon

Comment: When you will click on app icon and if there is any new notification  and your app is not launched then you can get the notification details in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of app delegate. Otherwise if app is in background state then there is no way to capture notification by tapping on app icon instead user has to tap on notification received and you can capture that in didRecieveRemoteNotification method of app delegate.

Comment: I think this is a bug, because sometimes I remove all my Notifications and later I see the badge and Click on it... Okay Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to read push notification data when user touched app icon on home screen.